# How to add info to a std::exception using boost exception

Tags: c++, exception, boost

The Boost Exception framework is great. You can add information to an exception derived from `std::exception` and `boost::exception` at the appropriate level of an application, as described [in the documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/exception/doc/motivation.html).

But how can such information be added if you do not control the throw site in the code, e.g. the std lib throws an exception, e.g. map throws out_of_range?

It *cannot* be caught as boost::exception, because it does not derive from it:

```
try {
  my_map.at(id);
} catch(boost::exception &e) { // NOT caught
  e << errinfo_desc("id not found, map out of range");
  throw;
}
```

It can be caught as std::exception because out_of_range derives from std::exception, but then *no* information can be added because it not a `boost::exception`:

```
try {
  my_map.at(id);
} catch(std::exception &e) {
  // compile error: e << errinfo_desc("id not found, map out of range"); 
  throw;
}
```

Catching a `std::exception` and throwing a new `boost::exception` *loses* the original location of the exception which is not desired:

```
try {
  my_map.at(id);
} catch(std::exception &e) {
  BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION(my_exception() 
                        << errinfo_desc("id not found, map out of range")); 
}
```

Is is possible to preserve the original exception with its location etc. and still be able to add more information later? How?

Comment: No it's not possible to do what you want.

Comment: Are there other/better workarounds than the my last method of catching the std::exception and throwing a boost::exception, or is that the best I can do?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Perhaps it _is_ possible to do what he _wants_ (who knows). Just not what he _asked_ for :)

Comment: Well, all I try to do is collect as much information as possible on all the different levels when an exception occurs, basically as explained for Boost Exception. @JoachimPileborg If you turn your comment into an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I use the `std::exception` hierarchy wherever possible. And when they are not sufficient, then I just derive my exception class from `std::exception`. Never had any use case for `boost::exception` (perhaps all my code is too simple for that, don't know).

But if you really want to combine both, here is a wild idea: use multiple inheritance. Code sketch (untested, more like pseudocode):

```
// two personalities in one exception object
class MyException: public std::exception, public boost::exception {
  explicit MyException(const std::exception& stdex) { ... }
  ... other ctors as needed...

  ... other stuff ...
};

...

try {
  my_map.at(id);
} catch (const std::exception& stdex) {
  MyException myex(stdex); // gets SOME of the std::exception information
  myex << errinfo_desc("id not found, map out of range"); // boost::exception goodies
  throw myex;
}
```

Obvious caveat: slicing issues when initialising MyException objects with a std::exception reference. And the usual problems with MI. You have been warned :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by catching both cases: `boost::exception` and `std::exception`

```
try {
    my_map.at(id);
} catch(boost::exception &e) { 
    // If already a boost exception, catch here and add information
    e << errinfo_desc("id not found, map out of range");
    throw;
} catch(std::exception &) {
    // Otherwise, catch here and convert to a boost exception
    try { boost::rethrow_exception( boost::current_exception() ); }
    catch( boost::exception& e ) { 
      e << errinfo_desc("id not found, map out of range"); 
      throw; 
    }    
}
```

If find it's a pain to write that much code, so I asked if there was a cleaner way of doing this: [Adding error_info to std::exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26477890/adding-error-info-to-stdexception)